# Waterproofing Shower with BathFitter Tub

Tags: bathroom, waterproofing

I'm re-tiling my shower and due to some mold/water damage or just bad material we ended up almost stripping everything down to the studs.  Of the 3 shower walls we had to put up new backerboard on two of them.

Because of budget/time/effort reasons we cannot remove the original bathtub, which remains in place with a Bathfitter acrylic insert.

Everything I have read about waterproofing says that ideally the backerboard is installed up to the edge of the tub flange and waterproofing membrane (*we'll be using Redguard*) should be applied over that joint to create a continuous waterproof surface.

Due to the way the original tub was installed, this is not possible.  What's my best option for moving forward so I dont end up with a leaky mess.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Standard operating procedure is to tile down to the tub, leaving a small gap between tile and tub, 1/8", and caulk the gap with silicone. Is there something in "*the way the original tub was installed*"  that is preventing you from that? Does the bathfitter have any bearing on that?

Comment: There is a gap where the old tub flange is behind the backerboard and the bathfitter sits over the existing tub but not quite at the same level or width of the old tub since it was installed when the old tiles were there.  I just want to be sure I'm not creating an area where water may seep through and just sit on the old tub.  I'm considering bridging the gap with Kerdi band and using DILEX-AS to cover and create a new "top" of the tub to start tiling from.  But that's just me making things up after reading a bunch of stuff.